# How to apply a typemap only on one function's arguement?

Tags: c++, swig

I'm trying to create a wrapper in Java for a C++ solution.

Having 2 fonctions in this C++ project :

```
int func1(const void* b);
int func2(const void* b);
```

I need to apply this rule (typemap) only on `int func2(const void* b);` :

```
%apply char *BYTE { const void* b };
```

This is a constraint because `const void *` use is different from a function to another.

**Remark :** I have no right to rename fucn1's argument from b to something else.

Thanks you.

Comment: Is this still unanswered?

Answer (score 3):

Try %clear between the declaration of func1 and func2:

```
%{
#include "funcs.h"
%}

%apply char *BYTE { const void* b };
int func1(const void* b);
%clear const void* b;

int func2(const void* b);
```

Note also that the name of a variable in a declaration  does not affect called code, i.e. you should be able to do

```
%{
#include "funcs.h"
%}

%apply char *BYTE { const void* b };
int func1(const void* b);
int func2(const void* c);
```

(although the header declares first arg as b, C++ args are all positional, the only place they matter is in the definition (not declaration) of a function body, which is not something that SWIG uses so above should work).

Comment: What if **func1** and **func2** are defined in an `%include`ed file.  Is it possible to insert the `%clear` directive in between func1 and func2 in that case?